# Using SSkeychain to store access_token & user login - AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, sskeychain

I'm trying to store the users username, password and the access_token the user gets when logging in. I have searched a lot and found others with similar problems. But I'm still pretty new in xcode and objective-c, so I don't know how to use this SSKeychain library:
[Soffes/SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain)

Comment: The github repository that you linked to has a very long and helpful readme. Did you read it? Did you try what it said? What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: I don't understand what i can try there :S It says: 'Working with the Keychain' and shows the class methods. How du i use this? I have added the pod and security.framework, but dont how and where i should store these keychains. @Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the value in Keychain use the below code -

`[SSKeychain setPassword:tfPAssword.text forService:@"UserPassword" account:@"com.myApp.app"];`

To retrieve the value use below code

`NSString *password = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"UserPassword" account:@"com.myApp.app"];`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Is the strings secure now then??

Comment: Yes the string will be secure now

Comment: Thanks! So nice @Rajatp